# Hide border if box-shadow supported

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div with a border and a box shadow:

```
div.my-div
{
    border: 1px solid #555;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 35px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

The border is ugly, but it's necessary for browsers that do not support the shadow (the div's background is the same color as the surrounding elements).

How can I detect whether the browser supports box-shadow, and remove the box shadow? Perhaps with javascript?

**Edit:** I want to do this without any dependencies (such as modernizr).

For example:

```
var boxShadowSupported = ???;
if (boxShadowSupported && typeof(document.getElementsByClassName) != 'undefined') {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('my-div');
  for (var i= 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].setAttribute('style', 'border: 0;');
  }
}
```

Comment: I would rather have an ugly border than add thousands of lines of javascript to my page.

Comment: What about: 2401b ~2.4kb http://modernizr.com/download/#-boxshadow-teststyles-testprop-testallprops-domprefixes

Comment: 2.5kb plus latency is more than I'm willing to add to my page load speed. It's already slow enough with all of my own code.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert anyways your css looks slow using a class & tag selector both.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether they have dial up or fibre or 3G, the latency of an extra javascript file is not worth it, just to make the page a tiny bit nicer.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert ok that's fine. Use polyfills then to make them working on all browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check box-shaddow browser support with javascript :

```
if ('boxShadow' in document.body.style ) 
{
    alert('I can support shadow!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
var foo=document.createElement("div");
foo.style.boxShadow="0px 0px 0px rgb(0,0,0)";
document.body.appendChild(foo);
var boxShadowSupported=foo.style.boxShadow?1:0;
```